# Why is the word "Halleluya" not translated in the siddur?

Tags: prayer-book

The word "halleluya" appears many times in the siddur.  Typically the word is not translated in a Hebrew-English siddur.  But the Hebrew word can be translated.  Why is the word "halleluya" typically not translated?

Comment: Probably because it's also an English word?

Comment: I think that once it's written in one word and not הללו יה it became a standalone term, that's imported to other languages as Halleluya and not "praise Lord". Just as English Mazal Tov.

Comment: BTW how would you translate the hebrew word?

Comment: @AlBerko [Mazel Tov is a thing in English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mazel%20tov)

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps, but shabbat and hosanna are also a English words (per Cambridge dictionary, e.g. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hosanna), and these words are usually translated.